# How do box collider collisions work mathematically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine, physx

I want to know how the Box Collider works in Unity. I have read all of the Unity documentation and PhysX documentation but there are not any detailed explanations as to exactly how they work (possibly because it's confidential IP).

How does a box collider know when it is intersecting/overlapping another box collider?

What metric is actually measured to know when a collision has taken place? Does it look to see if there is a point or vertex in the box collider is inside the volume of another collider? If so how does it know that a vertex is within the volume of another collider?

What are box colliders made from? Is it lots of small objects put together or is it one big object?

​

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: it's not confidential IP, it's just geometry math.

Comment: Each box collider is an array of 8 vertices, each with x,y,z positions. Thanks to math, if you know position of each of 8 vertices and position of a point you want to check then you can calculate if this point is inside a box made out of 8 vertices.

Comment: Asking how is determined if two boxes intersect is a boring question. Add the time component and ask how detecting collisions works in a discrete systems that simulates a continuous real system that gets more interesting, but off-topic here.

Comment: @FCin but you don't want to know if a point is inside a box. You want to know if two boxes intersect. Different problem. Same answer: geometry math.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26506/101664

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-ii-collision-detection-for-solid-objects